# Перевод в системы счисления

Tags: системы-счисления

Из любой системы счисления в десятичную можно перевести, используя только операции сложения и умножения(по схеме Горнера). Существует ли похожий алгоритм для перевода(используя только операции сложения и умножения) из десятичной в другие системы счисления(так как Горнер не работает в обратную сторону).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, есть. Тут в помощь приходит деление. [Смотри тут](http://ivanovff.21419s01.edusite.ru/uchin/p7aa1.html) или [вот тут](http://inf.e-alekseev.ru/text/Schisl_perevod.html).

Comment: Ты думаешь, я не знаю, как переводить делением? Мне нужен способ с использованием только операций сложения и умножения!

Comment: а ты не можешь вместо деления на 8, например, умножить на 0.125? целую часть возьмёшь, а дальше вычитанием (обратная сложению, тоже можно заменить) найдёшь остаток.